# Porque la lista remplaza los lista

Tags: javascript

Tengo que este código que quiero que agregue las palabras que solicito por pantalla en forma de lista, pero solo agrega la ultima palabra, no se que estoy haciendo mal.

Es el html y el estilo.

```
<head>
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css"> 

        ol,li{
            list-style-type: none;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>PALABRAS</h2>
    <div id=".">

        <p>Frase:</p>

        <ol></ol>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Esto es el script, hago un appendChild a lista en bucle for pero remplazada los elementos.

```
        let frase;
        let size=1;
        frase =prompt("Introduce Frase");
        if(frase === null){
            alert("No hay frase");
        }else{
            let li = document.createElement("li");
            size = 1; //'1 rem' 1+(1*0.25)
            let ol = document.getElementById(".").querySelector("ol");
            frase = frase.split(" ");               
            for(let d of frase){
                li.textContent=d;
                ol.appendChild(li);
                console.log(ol);
            }            
        }
```

Comment: Pues pasa que creas un elemento `li` y dentro de tu bucle le asignas todos los valores diferentes... pero sigue siendo el mismo elemento li. Probaste a crear el `li` dentro del bucle?

Comment: Favor pasar el script completo, bucle o función, para ver como lo estás haciendo, poder hacer pruebas y ayudarte. Lo puse en una función llamandose con un contador 5 veces, y funcionó perfecto.

Comment: Como bien dice @Benito-B, debes crear el `li` dentro del ciclo, porque [appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) crea un elemento solo si no existe, de lo contrario, lo mueve al contenedor deseado.

Comment: Gracias, probé la primera solución y funciono, esta declarando el li en sitio incorrecto